# Intersect sequence of strings `Seq[String]` with future set of strings `Future[Set[String]]`

Tags: scala

I want to find out if there is common elements between the two collections,
if it was not for the `Future` issue I would have done:

```
  def isThere(user: User, anyOf: String*): Future[Boolean] = {
    if(anyOf.nonEmpty) anyOf.intersect(user.getStuff.toSeq).nonEmpty
    else true
```

But this will not work because `getStuff` return type is `Future[Set[String]]` not to mention the whole return type of `Future[Boolean]` issue.

How can can get `isThere` to work while keeping it's return type intact ?

Comment: Could you please give example input and the expected output? Also - please show `User`'s definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map over the future to apply a function to it's result

```
case class User(getStuff: Future[Set[String]])

def isThere(user: User, anyOf: String*): Future[Boolean] = {
  if(anyOf.nonEmpty) user.getStuff.map(stuff => anyOf.intersect(stuff.toSeq).nonEmpty)
  else Future.successful(true)
}
```

Alternatively:

```
def isThere(user: User, anyOf: String*): Future[Boolean] = 
  user.getStuff.map {stuff => 
  if(anyOf.nonEmpty) anyOf.intersect(stuff.toSeq).nonEmpty
  else true
}
```

Comment: `Future.successful(true)` it's better than `Future(true)` as the earlier will create an already completed `Future` rather than creating a future and asynchronously completing it with `true` as the latter does.

Answer (score 1):

In order to access values contained in a `Future` you can use a function like `map` as Angelo pointed out. `map` on a `Future[A]` takes as a parameter a function `A => B` and returns a `Future[B]` (you can find more info about other methods on `Future` [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.concurrent.Future)).

Be aware that in order to `map`, `flatMap` etc over a future you will need an `implicit ExecutionContext`. This will inform the compiler who's going to take care of the asynchronous execution of your map function (as it is executed asynchronously, it's not on the same thread your process is running). In most cases you can use the [global implicit execution context](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext$$Implicits$) by typing `import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` (this will put it in scope).  However YMMV depending on your application needs and you may need to declare a dedicate `ExecutionContext` (for example from a Java `ExecutorService` using the syntax `implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(javaExecutor)`.